# Find and replace escape characters \' with '' in .sql filesize of 300 MB +

Tags: windows

How to find the escape characters of reverse-slash and single-quotation (\') and and replace with two single-quotations (''). I can do it in some text editor for small files. But these are large .sql files with file sizes ranging from 250MB to 750MB. Please let me know if you got any better thoughts. This is Windows env, so I cannot use any Linux based command line utilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out, this is not a database question, and you need to use a command line utility. In addition to perl and sed, PowerShell on Windows is capable of natively doing it. See https://superuser.com/questions/517760/how-to-search-and-replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-cmd-or-powershell for but one example of it. Search for `"powershell find replace"` on the Web and you will find plenty of guidance.

Comment: Thank you Yuri. I have Powershell, but got to know of get-content command through link provided.

Comment: Further, I have placed this question here as I thought its related to database. Anyways, I'll take care from next time about it. Thank You :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Database-specific question.

Use perl or sed. There are Windows ports for both, see https://www.perl.org/get.html#win32 and http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm .

Then it becomes

```
perl -pie"sm#\'#''#g" <file>
```

(maybe you'll have to escape more or less)

Comment: Thank you. I have used Powershell as it was already present in my system. And I asked this question here as I thought its related to database. Anyways, I'll take care from next time about it!!

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. I've had to do some search and replace where PowerShell actually added more formatting and inserted hidden characters in my search/replace--for .SQL files no less. I had to find something else.

I landed on the utility FART (Find and Replace Text) for Windows at http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/

It humorously works quite well...